# Cannot estimate gas on execution

Tags: solidity, remix

I am having trouble with a function that calls a function and sends funds of the same contract in another instance:

```
function buyLoan(address _sellLoan, address _sellPortfolio) public {

    uint tradePrice = Loan(_sellLoan).getBalance();

    // Now check if funds available
    if (tradePrice > address(this).balance) {
        // Not enough funds, so revert
        revert();
    } else {
        // Enough funds, so execute purchase

        // Get Sell Portfolio for transfer
        Portfolio sp = Portfolio(_sellPortfolio);

        // Finalize sale of Loan
        tr.executeTrade(_sellLoan, _tradeDate);

      if (!address(sp).send(tradePrice))
            revert();

        // Now add loan to buying portfolio
        addLoan(_sellLoan, tradePrice);

        // Delete loan from selling portfolio
        sp.deleteLoan(_sellLoan);
        }

}
```

When I try to run this function I get an error that it cannot estimate the gas required. The code compiles and there are no do while or for loops.

The problem I have is I am not even sure where to look to figure this out...

The exact error is:

> Gas estimation errored with the following message (see below). The
>   transaction execution will likely fail. Do you want to force sending? 
>   JsonRpcEngine - response has no error or result for request: {
>   "jsonrpc": "2.0", "id": 2522037241, "method": "eth_estimateGas",
>   "params": [ { "from": "0x6d4dcc21e77ee5bc18d0f91497fc5285a71c836a",
>   "to": "0x1B15f071B4Fbd625Ebb3cC389D856ea2Ba7284A5", "data":
>   "0x03fb6eb00000000000000000000000006f13ee53f5eced4021b768c2949f45c5075120890000000000000000000000001b15f071b4fbd625ebb3cc389d856ea2ba7284a5",
>   "value": "0x1001d1bf800" } ] }

I am compiling with remix using version ^0.4.25. I would appreciate any help you can give me.

Thanks.

Comment: Would be great if you can share the contract address on testnet so we can help you better.

Comment: Here is the contract adress:0x779c17a07b5f2D039C966E0cA1F98DB66eB82EC3

Comment: That's not contract. I think you pasted wrong address. You should redeploy it again if you have missed it. In addition to that, you should verify the code so that others can help you. https://medium.com/@Dave_Appleton/verifying-your-contract-on-etherscan-75a2afbf5b42

Answer (score 0):

This has now been solved. The problem was that there was not enough gas reserved when using send (namely 2300). Using call as Smarx helped me with here:

https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/65879/error-when-executing-transfer-with-sufficient-funds?noredirect=1#comment79515_65879

The critical line is that the command:

```
address(sp).send(tradePrice)
```

should be:

```
address(sp).call.value(tradePrice)("")
```

Anyway, thanks to all who responded and tried to help.